# Solving $\Re\left(\frac{z-1}{\overline z + i}\right)\le -1$

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

I cannot really come up how to solve it so I ask for help. I've tried to make some use of the expresion's argument, but couldn't come up with anything sensible.

$$\Re\left(\frac{z-1}{\overline z + i}\right)\le -1$$

Comment: Write $z=x+iy$, with $x,y$ real, and work it out.  Show us your efforts...

Comment: Multiply by the conjugate of $\bar z+i$ on the top and bottom of the fraction to get a real only denominator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\Re\left(\frac{z-1}{\overline{z}+i}\right) \leq -1 \Leftrightarrow \left[
\begin{array}{l}
z = x+iy \\
\overline{z} = x-iy
\end{array}
\right] \Leftrightarrow \\
&\Re\left(\frac{x+iy-1}{x-iy+i}\right) \leq -1 \Leftrightarrow \\
&\Re\left(\frac{(x-1)+iy}{x-i(y-1)}\right) \leq -1 \Leftrightarrow \\
&\Re\left(\frac{\left((x-1)+iy\right)\left(x+i(y-1)\right)}{\left(x-i(y-1)\right)\left(x+i(y-1)\right)}\right) \leq -1 \Leftrightarrow \\
&\Re\left(\frac{\left(x(x-1)-y(y-1)\right) + i\left(xy+(x-1)(y-1)\right)}{x^2+(y-1)^2}\right) \leq -1 \Leftrightarrow \\
&\frac{x(x-1)-y(y-1)}{x^2+(y-1)^2} \leq -1 
\end{aligned}
$$

Could you continue from here?